# How do I write log messages to a log file and the console at the same time?

Tags: python, logging

Does this code write to both a log file and the console at the same time?

```
logFile = open("logfile.log",a)
print >>logFile,message
logFile.close()
```

Comment: what did it do when you tried it....

Comment: its possible using multiple handler. one for handling file (`logging.FileHandler('mylog.log')`) and other for handling console (`logging.StreamHandler()`). see first example of https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, it will not write to both. `print()` will write to the console only. One quick note on your original code. I presume you define `message` somewhere, but the code is still incorrect. You need quotes around the `a` in the `open` statement, like this:

```
open("logfile.log", "a")
```

since I presume you meant to append to the file. Otherwise, you code throws a `NameError` since `a` is not a defined variable.

However, as others have said, you should strongly consider using the [logging](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.html#module-logging) module. Here is a simple example of how to write to both the console and a log file. The code is partially derived from [here](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#multiple-handlers-and-formatters) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11582124/869912):

```
import inspect
import logging

def function_logger(file_level, console_level = None):
    function_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]
    logger = logging.getLogger(function_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) #By default, logs all messages

    if console_level != None:
        ch = logging.StreamHandler() #StreamHandler logs to console
        ch.setLevel(console_level)
        ch_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
        ch.setFormatter(ch_format)
        logger.addHandler(ch)

    fh = logging.FileHandler("{0}.log".format(function_name))
    fh.setLevel(file_level)
    fh_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(lineno)d - %(levelname)-8s - %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(fh_format)
    logger.addHandler(fh)

    return logger

def f1():
    f1_logger = function_logger(logging.DEBUG, logging.ERROR)
    f1_logger.debug('debug message')
    f1_logger.info('info message')
    f1_logger.warn('warn message')
    f1_logger.error('error message')
    f1_logger.critical('critical message')

def f2():
    f2_logger = function_logger(logging.WARNING)
    f2_logger.debug('debug message')
    f2_logger.info('info message')
    f2_logger.warn('warn message')
    f2_logger.error('error message')
    f2_logger.critical('critical message')

def main():
    f1()
    f2()
    logging.shutdown()

main()
```

Since logger objects can have more than one handler, we can create multiple handlers that write to different places. In my code, the `function_logger` function creates a logger object specific to the function in which it's called.

The function `f1()` logs `DEBUG` level messages and above to a file `f1.log`, while writing `ERROR` level messages and above to the console, with different formatting for each.

The function `f2()`, however, logs nothing to the console and only logs `WARNING` level messages to its log file `f2.log`. Running this script once yields this output on the console:

```
2012-07-20 10:46:38,950 - f1  - error message
2012-07-20 10:46:38,953 - f1  - critical message
```

and this output in `f1.log` and `f2.log`, respectively:

**f1.log**:

```
2012-07-20 10:46:38,950 - 26 - DEBUG    - debug message
2012-07-20 10:46:38,950 - 27 - INFO     - info message
2012-07-20 10:46:38,950 - 28 - WARNING  - warn message
2012-07-20 10:46:38,950 - 29 - ERROR    - error message
2012-07-20 10:46:38,953 - 30 - CRITICAL - critical message
```

**f2.log**

```
2012-07-20 10:46:38,960 - 36 - WARNING  - warn message
2012-07-20 10:46:38,960 - 37 - ERROR    - error message
2012-07-20 10:46:38,960 - 38 - CRITICAL - critical message
```

Comment: One detail: As of Py27, the line "logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) #By default, logs all messages" is essential. Without it, the setLevel() calls for the handlers wouldn't work: The detail level would be locked on logging.warning.

Answer (score 0):

No. It writes to file only. You should use `logging` module. See http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html