# How do I change the format of a Python log message on a per-logger basis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

After reading the [documentation on `logging`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.html#module-logging), I know I can use code like this to perform simple logging:

```
import logging

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(filename="messages.log",
                        level=logging.WARNING,
                        format='%(filename)s: '    
                                '%(levelname)s: '
                                '%(funcName)s(): '
                                '%(lineno)d:\t'
                                '%(message)s')

    logging.debug("Only for debug purposes\n")
    logging.shutdown()

main()
```

However, I realised I don't know how to change the format of log messages on a per-logger basis, since `basicConfig` is a module-level function. This code works for creating different loggers with different levels, names, etc. but is there a way to change the format of those log messages on a per-logger basis as well, in a way similar to `basicConfig`?

```
import inspect
import logging

def function_logger(level=logging.DEBUG):
    function_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]
    logger = logging.getLogger(function_name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler("{0}.log".format(function_name)))
    return logger

def f1():
    f1_logger = function_logger()
    f1_logger.debug("f1 Debug message")
    f1_logger.warning("f1 Warning message")
    f1_logger.critical("f1 Critical message")

def f2():
    f2_logger = function_logger(logging.WARNING)
    f2_logger.debug("f2 Debug message")
    f2_logger.warning("f2 Warning message")
    f2_logger.critical("f2 Critical message")

def main():
    f1()
    f2()
    logging.shutdown()

main()
```

Comment: You just helped me to figure out how to add filename, function name, and line number to my logs.  Thanks

Comment: @XanderYzWich See https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes for the full list of available attributes

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Try this

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create file handler that logs debug and higher level messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('spam.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create console handler with a higher log level
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.addHandler(fh)

# 'application' code
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

See http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#multiple-handlers-and-formatters for more information

Comment: +1, and +1 again (sadly no) for adding the code. I edited it into my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11581118/869912) to a logging question as well, and it works perfectly.

Comment: I am always surprised it's not as simple as `logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')   logger.basicConfig(level=..., format=...)`...

Comment: Only the `logging` module has the [`basicConfig` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)

Comment: @tread yes, that's the problem/criticism here.

Comment: @theartofrain On the other hand, by setting the format on each handler, you can make one format for stdout and another for the file log. But it would be nice to simplify the way we set the format for formatting as well. Is it really necessary for us to create a Formatter object? Shouldn't we be able to just pass the format string to setFormatter(), and let it deal with any conversion inside the method?

Comment: When will they change this madness? Who knows

Answer (score 2):

You  have to create or use an existing subclass of `logging.Handler` and call the `setformatter()` method of an instance thereof with an instance of a custom subclass of `logger.Formatter`.  If you set the formatter for a handler that was already attached to the logger you want to modify the output of, you are fine, otherwise you have to retrieve a logger object with `logging.getLogger()` and call its `addHandler()` method with the instance of your handler class that you set the formatter on as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

logging.basicConfig(filename = file_path, level = logging.INFO, format = '%(message)s')